# Proof for this identity: $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(\zeta(2k+3)-1) = \frac{1}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, geometric-series

$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\zeta(2k+3) 
-1) = \frac{1}{4}
$$
I found this nice identity and want to prove it, but I don't know how.
My first thought was that I can create a geometric series with the same limit like:
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{1}{2^k} = \frac{1}{4}$$
But I have no idea, how to write the first one in a way, that these are the same. They are obviously only equal, if we sum infinitely many terms together.
Do you have ideas, how to proof this identity or do you know, where the proof can be found?
Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Where did you found it? All terms are greater than 1!

Comment: You have a typo, should be $\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\zeta(2k+3) - \color{red}{1}) = \frac14$.

Comment: Actually , this sum seems to be $k+\frac{5}{4}$ with a very small error already for $k=10$

Answer (score 5):

There is a typo in the question.
The sum $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \zeta(2k+3)$ diverges because $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} \zeta(2k+3) = 1$.
The correct statement should be

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (\zeta(2k+3) - 1) = \frac14$$

The proof is relatively simple,

$$\begin{align} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (\zeta(2k+3)-1)
= &\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2k+3}}
\stackrel{\color{blue}{[1]}}{=} \sum_{n=2}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2k+3}}
= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{k=0}^\infty (n^{-2})^k\\
= &\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}\frac{1}{1 - n^{-2}}
= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{(n-1)n(n+1)}
= \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac12\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)n} - \frac{1}{n(n+1)}\right)\\
\stackrel{\color{blue}{[2]}}{=} & \frac12\left(\frac{1}{(2-1)2}\right) = \frac14\end{align}
$$

**Notes**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - all terms are non-negative, it is legal to exchange order of summation.
- $\color{blue}{[2]}$ - the sum is a telescoping one.

Comment: Wow, so easy is that (if one has the "know-how") (+1)

Comment: The concept of a telescoping sum is very fascinating. I was not aware of this type of series

Answer (score 3):

By the [integral representation of $\zeta\left(s\right)$](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) we have $$\zeta\left(2k+3\right)-1=\frac{1}{\left(2k+2\right)!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{2k+2}}{e^{u}\left(e^{u}-1\right)}du$$ then $$\sum_{k\geq0}\left(\zeta\left(2k+3\right)-1\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{u}\left(e^{u}-1\right)}\sum_{k\geq0}\frac{u^{2k+2}}{\left(2k+2\right)!}du$$ $$=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cosh\left(u\right)-1}{e^{u}\left(e^{u}-1\right)}du=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}-e^{-2u}du=\color {red}{\frac{1}{4}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{\zeta\pars{2k + 3} - 1}}} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\bracks{\zeta\pars{2k + 1} - 1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\lim_{z \to 1}\bracks{{1 \over 2z} - {1 \over 2}\,\pi\,\cot\pars{\pi z} -
{1 \over 1 - z^{2}} + 1 - \gamma - \Psi\pars{1 + z}} = \bbx{1 \over 4}
\end{align}

> where $\ds{\Psi}$ is the *Digamma Function*. See [$\ds{\mathbf{\color{black}{6.3.15}}}$ in A & S Table](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm).
>   
> Note that
>   $\ds{\Psi\pars{2} = \Psi\pars{1} + 1 = -\gamma + 1}$.